# Firebase Storage Image upload - Function to return the Image URL after uploading it

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await, firebase-storage

I need to implement this async function,

```
const uploadImage = async () => {
  const filename = new Date().getTime() + photo!.name
  const storage = getStorage(app)
  const storageRef = ref(storage, filename)
  const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, photo!);
  
  uploadTask.on('state_changed',
    (snapshot) => {},
    (error) => {
      console.log("error while uploading photo", error)
    },
    async () => {
      photoUrl = await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref);
      console.log("getDownloadURL", photoUrl)
      return photoUrl
    }
  );
}
```

It is the function to upload images to Firebase-Storage. Here I need to return the "photoUrl ". I need to call the function like,

```
const res = await uploadImage(photo)
```

how do I do this? The uploaded image's URL should return from the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object returned by `uploadBytesResumable` is also a promise, so you can just `await` that and then call `getDownloadURL`:

```
const uploadImage = async () => {
  const filename = new Date().getTime() + photo!.name
  const storage = getStorage(app)
  const storageRef = ref(storage, filename)
  const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, photo!);
  await uploadTask;
  photoUrl = await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref);
  return photoUrl
}
```

You actually don't even need a reference to the task, as you already have the `storageRef`, the above can be shorted to:

```
const uploadImage = async () => {
  const filename = new Date().getTime() + photo!.name
  const storage = getStorage(app)
  const storageRef = ref(storage, filename)
  await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, photo!);
  return await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is same thing to upload multiple files to firebase and return their URLs

```
  async function uploadMultipleFilesToFirebase(imagesArray) {
    try {
      const requests = imagesArray.map(async (imageFile) => {
        const storageRef = ref(storage, filename)
        await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, imageFile);
        return await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
      })

      return Promise.all(requests)
    } catch (error) {
      throw({ error })
    }
  }
```

And then use it with:

```
urlsOfUploadedImages.value = await uploadProductToFirebase(productData)
```